# How to bound $\sum_{ j=1}^n j^{n-j}?$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, upper-lower-bounds

I came across this sum in some research I'm doing.  I need to bound

$$S_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}j^{n-j}.$$

One bound I've managed is obtained by doing the following: Divide by n! and observe

$S_n/n!=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{j^{n-j}}{(n)...(j+1)}\frac{1}{(j)!}\leq\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(j)!}\leq e-1$

So that

$S_n\leq (e-1)n!$,

but I was wondering if this can be improved at all as this seems like a pretty crude bound.

Comment: Are you suggesting that $$\frac{j^{n-j}}{n(n-1)(\cdots (n-j+1)}\leq 1?$$ Is that obvious? Or even true? Doesn’t seem true when $j=2$ and $n$ large.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake.  This is only trivially true for j < (n+1)/2.  Let me redo the proof.

Comment: I fixed it.  Just made a mistake in the first equality, my bad.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A026898 for more info (I found the duplicate on MSE via the OIES page).

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you, I wasn't able to find it myself.